# My JS Accordion is acting goofy - it jumps all over the place

Tags: css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to implement a `js` accordion I found and I'm having problems with it. The titles are supposed to cleanly slide up to the top of the page and drop the content below. That is not what is happening. There is some obvious jumpiness going on when you look at it. It's not smooth at all. I don't know much about `js` so please explain your answers carefully. Thanks so much!

http://imip.rvadv.com/accordion.html

**EDIT:**
After replacing the js with the default file from the site I got it from, nothing changed. Here is a jsfiddle for it

http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/ruwjn/

Comment: You would do well to add actual code to your question. Create a [reduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Reducing_testcases) of the problem to help people help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/ruwjn/4/

The problem wasn't the .js, and you don't have to write it all on jsfiddle, since it's JQuery UI, you can simple check it to include it, if it's another external .js, use it as a resource, check [fiddle's documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/) for that.

Besides that, the other problem was your **CSS** markup, you had a lot of duplicated classes in that fiddle, it was a bit of a mess.

The main problem with the jumping was the:

```
.st-accordion ul li.st-open > a{
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

I just commented that `margin-top: 70px;`, and it fixed 75% of the problem, I recommend you to use the css that I arrange on the jsfiddle.

Hope it helps you!

---

**UPDATE**

Now, if you want to scroll all the way up like http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/ruwjn/5/ you need to make the body higher on height:

```
body {
    height: 2000px; 
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but all of the links are doing the same thing. When I click on "chirp", it acts correctly. It scrolls up to the top of the page and opens. When I click the next item, "Bird's Eye", it opens and scrolls up, but not all the way to the top.

Comment: If you want to scroll all the way up for every link/item of the accordion, you need to make your `body height higher`, for example 2000px, check the edit of the question

Comment: Ok, so I used the exact css you gave me and everything worked smoothly. Then, I added in the 70px top margin and the jump came back. It slides up to the correct height but first it drops down a little. http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html#resume

Comment: Also, If I give the body a height of 2000px, then my footer doesn't stick to the bottom. There's a huge gap below it.

Comment: @imakeitpretty ok! open a new question so i can see the full detail and i'll check it out! Btw, did you check your other question with the accordion? I uploaded a short video

Comment: OH DUH! I misread your comment. You said DONT add the margin 70px! Ok, so I took that out and you're right that solves the problem of the jumping. I still need to get the menu to slide up to below the top header instead of under it. Argh! This is driving me crazy!

Comment: I accidentally deleted the question before I got to look at the video. I started a new question to specifically address the top header margin issue. Thanks again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Here's the vid: http://www.screencast.com/users/Cuartico/folders/Jing/media/e6958bd7-f4d4-4573-b914-94784588df07 lemme check that new question...

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code, you appear to be using this plugin:

```
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/
```

If you go to that page, it has the javascript options you need to control the animation speeds, as well as a working example which is more smooth than yours.

Comment: I replaced the `js` with the default `js` from that site and it didn't do anything. I think this is an issue with my css.